# Reinstall python and make import numpy work

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy

First of all, I should say, that I checked all links at `stackoverflow`, but I still can't make it work. What I want is just as simple as my nose - I want to import `numpy` and I want to import modules created by `f2py`. Now, when I do in console

```
$ python
>> import numpy
```

I get an error `No module named numpy`. In the same way I get an error, when I try to import a `fortran` module made by `f2py`:

```
>> import testmodule
```

My OS is `Ubuntu 12.04`. I should also add, that I tried to uninstall and reinstall python hundreds of times with different libs and of course I did `sudo apt-get install python-numpy` etc. But that didn't help. What I want to hear from you, guys, is a complete step-by-step instruction (including unintallation of the current versions of python which may be corrupt and including installation instructions - download this version, unpack it to here etc.) I guess that instruction will be extremely worthy and usefull for python newbeis like me. The problem that I face now seems to be the simplest in the  world, but I wonder why it has no simple solution.

Comment: Wonder why people are downvoting a newbee question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your Python prompt have `>>` as the prompt?  I've always seen `>>>` from Python.

If uninstalling Python and reinstalling doesn't work, perhaps the problem is with your user account?  I'd try:

- Create a new user, `sudo useradd joe`
- Log in as the new user `sudo -u joe bash -login`
- See if Python and numpy work now.
- Exit from joe's shell (exit, logout or ^D).
- Get rid of joe, `sudo userdel joe`

Now at least you know if the problem is with your system setup or your user setup.

Other things to look for:

- run `pip freeze | grep numpy` or `pip freeze | less` to see which `numpy` package is (or isn't) installed.
- Do you have something odd in your environment?  Try `env | grep -i python` to see if you have a nonstandard environment variable.
- Do you have `python` aliased to something else in your `.profile` or other startup?  Try `alias python` to see if you really are starting python when you run `python`.
- Do you have some old python in your `$PATH`?  You can try `which python` and you should see `/usr/bin/python`.  If you get '/usr/local/bin/python`that should be a link pointing to the "real" python at`/usr/bin/python`.
- Have a look at `/usr/bin/python`.  It should be a link to `python2.7`.

During your uninstall-reinstall cycles, you can run `pip freeze` to see the list of installed packages.  You should be able to make `numpy` appear and disappear in the freeze list when you install and uninstall it.